# Rx - How to merge Single and Observables using Rx?

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java

I'm trying to create a Rx Chain so that I can have an Observable that can emit items, before and after executing a Single that will emit the same type of items.

Please check the example below:

```
    fun main() {
        val namesObservable = Observable.just(listOf("A", "B", "C"), listOf("D", "E", "F"))
        namesObservable
            .flatMapSingle { names -> addCharSingle(names) }
            .subscribe { item ->
                println(item.joinToString())
            }
    }

    fun addCharSingle(letters: List<String>): Single<List<String>> {
        return Single.fromCallable { letters.map { letter -> "$letter!" } }
    }
```

This implementation will print:
"A!, B!, C!",
"D!, E!, F!"

But I want it to print:
"A, B, C",
"A!, B!, C!",
"D, E, F",
"D!, E!, F!"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

1. Instead of `flatMapSingle`, use `flatMap`
2. Inside, use two `Single`s concatenated with each other.

- The first would have the original list, the second would do the conversion.

3. Lastly, convert it to `Observable` because `Single.concatWith` returns `Flowable` by design.

```kotlin
val namesObservable = Observable.just(
      listOf("A", "B", "C"), listOf("D", "E", "F"))

namesObservable
    .flatMap { names -> 
         Single.just(names)
            .concatWith(addCharSingle(names))
            .toObservable()
    }
    .subscribe { item ->
        println(item.joinToString())
    }
```